# Calling/Executing "UIVERI 5" by pressing a button / calling a function from a website

Tags: node.js, angularjs, reactjs, sap-fiori, uiveri5

I have developed some test cases using the JS framwork "UIVERI5" and execute those by running

```
UIVER5
```

in the terminal / console. Now I want to execute those test cases by integrating them into a website.
For that I am using the JS framework Angular (could switch to others). Both frameworks, UIVERI5 and Angular are installed in the same project folder and can be started seperatly using the terminal. 
How is it possible to execute UIVERI5 within the runtime of the website?
Any suggestion or cluse would help.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is wondering about that in the future: 
I have found no way to start "UIVERI5" from the website.
Possible solution is to start "uiveri5.js", but I have not accomplished that.
I have switched to electron, as there is the possibility to start shell scripts.